Return an integer from a Task
I watched this video to create an async function that doesn't block my winforms GUI.
C# Async / Await - Make your app more responsive and faster with asynchronous programming
That works great and now I'm looking for advice on how to return an int from a task.
MainUI.cs
private void button_StartStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!Profile.ProfileLoaded)
     {

         return;
     }

     if (!UABA.Status)
     {
         button_StartStop.BackgroundImage = ((Image)(Properties.Resources.Stop_Button));
         UABA.Status = true;
         Task.Run(() => Main.RunAsync(this));
     }
     else
     {
         button_StartStop.BackgroundImage = ((Image)(Properties.Resources.Play_Button));
         UABA.Status = false;
     }
}

Main.cs
public static async Task RunAsync(MainUI form_mainUI)
{
    while (true)
    {                
        if (UABA.Status)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => GameData.GetCharacterWindowInformationAsync());
        
            UI.GameData.Character.UpdateCurrentManaValue();
            UI.GameData.Character.UpdateCurrentReadiness();                                     
        }
    }
}

GameData.cs
public static async Task GetCharacterWindowInformationAsync()
{
    List<Task<int>> tasks = new List<Task<int>>();

    if (MonitorMana.MonitoringManaBar)
    {
        var gameData = new GameData();         
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => gameData.ReadPixelsInALineAsync()));
    }
    if (MonitorReadiness.MonitoringReadinessBar)
    {
        var gameData = new GameData();
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => gameData.GetCurrentReadiness()));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);     

    //When this is finished waiting, I want to use the return int value from each task to update different variables that are used in the GUI (ie. currentMana and currentReadiness).      
}

public Task<int> ReadPixelsInALineAsync()
{
    //Do Work Here

    return Task.FromResult(resultOfSomeWork);
}


Why are you doing a Task.Run on methods that are already async?

I assume you have many more that two tasks in GetCharacterWindowInformationAsync?

@Enigmativity it seems that based on the Task.FromResult(resultOfSomeWork) they are really not really asynchronous)))

@Enigmativity I thought if I wanted work done on a separate thread I needed to use Task.Run?
There's only two tasks for now, but once I get this working I have more planned.

@GuruStron Why does doing it that way make them synchronous?

@bjcasey - You may or may not get a separate thread, but I would generally let the lowest level code in the async call chain work that out. You're probably just adding additional overhead for no benefit.
